# Different syntax to add/substract interval

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, timestamp, operator

Till now I used the following syntax to add an interval to a timestamp:

```
select now() + '5 year';
```

This worked fine till I tried to subtract the interval which results in a syntax error.

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "5 year"
LINE 1: select now() - '5 year'
```

In the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html) I learned that the syntax actually is:

```
select now() - interval '5 year'
```

So my questions are:
Why does `select now() + '5 year'` work at all?
Does it work only by accident and it might break in a future Postgresql release?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is on-topic as "Basic SQL" questions are off-topic. But I am not sure if this is still "Basic SQL"...

Comment: 100 % OT, let me assure you. Not as trivial as it may seem.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter does "OT" stand for "On Topic" or "Off Topic"?

Comment: @Brad: Sorry for the ambiguity. **On Topic**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @a_horse explained, there are two operators available for the expression `now() - '5 year'`:

- [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) returns `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`).
- `'5 year'` is an [untyped string literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.4.2).

```
SELECT oprleft::regtype, oprname, oprright::regtype
FROM   pg_operator
WHERE  oprname = '-'
AND    oprleft = 'timestamptz'::regtype;

         oprleft          | oprname |         oprright         
--------------------------+---------+--------------------------
 timestamp with time zone | -       | timestamp with time zone
 timestamp with time zone | -       | interval
(2 rows)
```

The ***exact*** reason for the choice can be found in the manual in the chapter [***Operator Type Resolution***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html):

> [...]
>
> `2.` Check for an operator accepting exactly the input argument types. If one exists (there can be only one exact match in the set of
>   operators considered), use it. [...]
>
> `a.` If one argument of a binary operator invocation is of the **unknown type, then assume it is the same type** as the other argument for this check. [...]
>
> [...]

**Bold** emphasis mine. Read the whole chapter to understand the process fully.

The **same type** is preferred if one argument type is unknown and a matching operator is available. There is an operator for `timestamptz - timestamptz`, bingo. The operator is resolved here. *Fortunately*, '5 years' is illegal input for `timestamptz`, else this might result in confusion!

The operator resolves to `timestamptz - interval` after adding an **explicit type cast**:

```
now() - interval '5 year'  -- always the way to go
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess(!) is:

The `+` operator for timestamps only supports adding an interval (`timestamp + interval`). And thus it's clear that the string value `'5 year'` needs to be (implicitly) converted to an `interval`

The `-` operator on the other hand supports two different combinations:

- `timestamp - timestamp`
- `timestamp - interval`.

Apparently Postgres prefers to use the `timestamp - timestamp` option and tries to (implicitly) convert `'5 year'` to a timestamp which of course fails.

Comment: I thought this was due to the fact that `timestamptz` (not `timestamp`)  is the preferred type among ["Date/time types" in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) - and commented as much. But on a second look, there seems to be a different explanation. And `interval` is not a "Date/time type", but a "Timespan type" in the Postgres type system. (Your answer is still basically right.)